# Login failed for user while executing Python script from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute Python script using T-SQL which connect to SQL Server. I am getting login failed for user error. I am using windows authentication.

[image]

Same script I am executing from Pycharm and it runs successfully.

[image]

In addition when I use SQL Server authentication and execute from SQL server it runs successfully.

[image]

What I have done so far:

1. I added current user to SQLRUserGroup
   [image]
2. I added SQLRGroup to SQL Server logins

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please refer to [SQL R Library RDOBC Script to Connect to SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/r-library-rodbc-script-to-connect-sql-server-database.aspx)

Although I experience a similar issue when I use R script, the solution is related with SQL Server Configuration and SQLRUserGroup for your SQL Server instance.

I enabled TCP/IP protocol and added the SQLRUserGroup to the target database with login enabled.

Comment: Sometimes the errors are very similar, please check if it is exactly the same error. Also please check the instance. Are you using named instance or default instance. I could execute cursor.execute() and return data with Python too.

Comment: first you have to add current SQL Server instance R user group (where you execute the R script) as a Windows login on target SQL Server instance. how to do this?

Comment: Do I have to create new user SQLRUserGroupMSSQLSERVER and add this user to SQLRUserGroup and finally add this group to SQL Server login

Comment: I have SQL Server Machine Learning Services installed as a component on my local machine. This created a user group. In my case it is SQLRUserGroupSQL2019CTP21  . That will be different in your case according to the instance name you have chosed

Comment: I have edited the answer can you verify this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I also enabled the TCP/IP protocol for the instance using SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Actually I see in my codes I did not use the port number

Comment: Yes. It's weird though. I added Trusted_Connection as a first argument and it works.